# Passing JavaScript select value between forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, electron

I'm in need of some expert JavaScript advice.  I'm coding using Electron.

The issue:  I'm trying to capture the value selected from the second of two dropdown lists and pass it back into a JavaScript file.  The code below is ordered as it would run.  The dropdown code is not shown as it is simply populated by the viewProvinces function below.  The first dropdown's id is "country-select" while the second is "province-select".

In this case, a link is clicked in Index.html which calls the anonymous function in Data.js.  The anonymous function calls viewProvinces that populates the parray/data variables from the anonymous function which produces the alert showing the value returned.

(FYI) viewProvinces also populates the second dropdown (id province-select) by filtering based on the values produced in the first dropdown (id country-select). For example, if Afghanistan is selected as a country in the first, then only provinces from Afghanistan are shown in the second.

Moving on, viewProvinces calls Provinces which is an array populated when it calls getProvinces after querying a SQLite database for the source data.

ViewProvinces, Provinces, and getProvinces all work correctly.  The link and the anonymous function are the issue and technically work in that they produce *a* result, but not the *correct* result.  When the link is clicked it produces "object Object".  I believe I understand why it is doing this, though I am not skilled enough (yet) to know how to fix it.  I do not know how to adjust the code so that it returns the actual value(s) selected from the second (provinces) dropdown.

Put simply, the data is gathered from a SQL query that populates a series of arrays that further populates the dropdown list.  The value of this list, once selected, should be returned back to the source JavaScript file into a variable (it fails here).

Apologies if this sounds convoluted, but I'm trying to be thorough.  Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!!

Index.html:

```
<a id="test-select" href="#">test</a>
```

Data.js:

```
$( "#test-select" ).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var parray = viewProvinces($("#country-select").val());
var data = $('#test-select').data(parray);
alert(data);
});
```

View.js:

```
function viewProvinces(ccode) {
var viewPro = Provinces(function(results) {
    // Code only gets triggered when Provinces() calls return done(...); 
    var container = document.getElementById('province-select');
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    results.filter(function(el) {
        return el.ccode === ccode;
    }).forEach(function(loc, index) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.textContent = loc.pname;
        opt.value = loc.pcode;
        fragment.appendChild(opt);
    });
    container.appendChild(fragment);
});
}
```

Model.js:

```
function Provinces(done) {
//Pull location values from data
return getProvinces(done);
}
```

Data.js:

```
function getProvinces(done) {
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var file = 'db/locations.sqlite3';
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
var stmt = 'SELECT Country.CountryId, Country.CountryCode, Country.CountryName, Province.ProvinceName, Province.ProvinceCode FROM Province INNER JOIN Country ON Province.CountryId = Country.CountryId'
var larray = [];

db.all(stmt, function(err, rows) {
    //  This code only gets called when the database returns with a response.
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        larray.push({
            ccode: row.CountryCode,
            cname: row.CountryName,
            pname: row.ProvinceName,
            pcode: row.ProvinceCode
        });
    })
return done(larray);
});
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to answer your question via a fiddle based on your code created [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67p21Lh5/) but I had some trouble understanding a couple of things in your code, so I might have missed something. The main change I made was to make the `Provinces(function(results) {..` function return the array of filtered provinces:

```
function viewProvinces(ccode) {

    return Provinces(function(results) {
        var provinces = [];
        // Code only gets triggered when Provinces() calls return done(...); 
        var container = document.getElementById('province-select');
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        results.filter(function(el) {
            return el.ccode === ccode;
        }).forEach(function(loc, index) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.textContent = loc.pname;
            opt.value = loc.pcode;
            fragment.appendChild(opt);
            provinces.push(loc);
        });
        container.appendChild(fragment);
        return provinces;
    });
```

Once this is done, the `parray` is correctly setup:

`var parray = viewProvinces($("#country-select").val());`

However, I was confused when I read this code:

`var data = $('#test-select').data(parray);
alert(data);`

I assumed you were trying to save the `provinces` data in the link's store, so modified the code as follows to demo that it works:

```
    $('#test-select').data({
        provinces: parray
    }); // Save the provinces array

    var data = $('#test-select').data(); // Retrieve the provinces array

    //Dump it on the console
    $.each(data.provinces, function(index, province) {
        console.log("Province[" + index + "].name: " + province.cname);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It's a step forward.  I'm receiving the following error (Uncaught ReferenceError: viewProvinces is not defined) when trying to run.  I switched out the code for viewProvinces with what you provided as well as placed the "var data = $(..." and "$( '#test-select' ).data({..." into data.js.

Thoughts?

Comment: `viewProvinces is not defined` indicates the function is not visible in the scope where it's invoked i.e. in the `click` handler; check there's no typos, bad code etc in `view.js` to ensure that it's loaded correctly by the browser. Check if other global functions defined in `view.js` are visible